# Replace a String with a substring of the first one

Tags: node.js, shell

I am looking for a sed command or even with node **replace** a way to do this:

file.txt:

```
  ....
  ISODate("Something inside"),
  ....
  ISODate("Other thing"),
  ....
```

Pass sed command or a node command to file.txt and the output would be:

```
  ....
  "Something inside",
  ....
  "Other thing",
  ....
```

I am trying to use regexp in replace but I can't remove the last ')'.

Any idea??

Comment: `var regex = /ISODate\((.*)\)/; `  `var string = ' ISODate("Something inside")';`

Comment: var regex = /ISODate\((.*)\)/g;
var chain = "Testing ISODate('Hello') end of the sentence...";
var newChain = chain.replace(regex, "");

Returns: Testing  end of the sentence...

I am looking for : Testing Hello end of the sentence...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for you exmaple:

```
sed "s/^\(.*\)ISODate(\(.*\))\(.*\)$/\1\2\3/g" file.txt
```

Comment: Definitly yes! Thank you!